# Como passar parâmetros do component para vuex em um projeto Laravel e vuejs?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, axios, vuex

Estou utilizando em meu projeto o Vuex com modules e axios para trabalhar com a API criada em Laravel, como passar parâmetros em uma edição de um dado recuperado de uma API
Tenho minha Store

```
export default {
    state: {
        items: {
            data: []
        },
    },
    mutations:{

    },
    actions:{
        editCategories(context, params)
        {
            context.commit('PRELOADER', true)
            return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
                    axios.put(`/api/v1/categorys/${id}`, params)
                    .then(response=>resolve())
                    .catch(error=>reject(error))
                    .finally(()=>{
                        context.commit('PRELOADER', false)
                    })
                })
        }
    },
    getters: {

    }
}
```

em meu component estou tentando passar os dados para minha chamada na Api, mas está ocorrendo o seguinte erro

```
Vue warn]: Error in v-on handler: "TypeError: this.$store.dispatch(...).then(...).cath is not a function"
```

meu component basicamente é:

```
<template>
    <div>
        Editar
        <form v-on:submit.prevent="editForm">
           <input v-model="category.name" type="text">
           <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Cadastrar</button>
       </form>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
    props:{
        id:{
            require:true
        }
    },
    created(){
        this.$store.dispatch('loadCategorie', this.id)
        .then((response)=>{
            this.category = response
        })
        .catch((error)=>{
            console.log(error)
        })
    },
    data(){
        return {
            category:{
                name:''
            }
        }
    },
    methods:{
        editForm() {
            this.$store.dispatch('editCategories',this.id,{name: this.category.name})
           .then()
           .cath()
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

creio que o erro esteja acontecendo em:

```
 this.$store.dispatch('editCategories',this.id,{name: this.category.name})
```

como passar estes parâmetros corretamente?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apenas uma falta de chave para um determinado valor.

troquei isso:

```
this.$store.dispatch('editCategories',this.id,{name: this.category.name})
```

por isso:

```
this.$store.dispatch('editCategories',{id:this.id,name: this.category.name})
```

como não estava atribuindo nenhuma chave, o valor chegava como null.

"chave":"valor"

Answer (score 0):

O erro meniconado está na sintaxe. Não existe cath, o correto é catch.

```js
editForm() {
  this.$store.dispatch('editCategories',this.id,{name: this.category.name})
  .then()
  .cath()
}
```